# .net application in autostart crashes after user login, but runs when strated manually

Tags: c#, .net

I've got an .net (4.0 , 4.5 used on target machines) C# application wich is startet after user login via autostart.

The app crashes on some systems (mostly embedded PCs running Win7). 
This happens only when the user logs in. When the app has crashed and you start it manually, everything works fine.

If after a reboot / new login the app is startet manually ,theres no problem.

If I start via autostart and wait a minute before

```
Application.Run(new Form_Hauptfenster(serviceMonitor));
```

theres even no problem

I made a workaround wich catches the exception and start te app again. Sometimes it crahes a second time, but then it runs without any problems.

I`ve noticed that this happens more often on systems that have a heavy load after userlogin / boot (virusscanner / sql server / other software startet at the same time on weaker hardware).

Unluckily I can't reproduce the error on my development machine, but I had the chance to debug on a machine where the app crashes.

The crash occures when a method tries to change the colour of a panel in the main form. Seems like the main from got destroyed, theres no valid reference to the form any longer.

Has anyone an idea why the problem occurs and why this is only after boot / user login?
How can I solve the problem?

Many thanks for your help,

Micha

The .net Error is like: `CLR20R3 / system.windows.forms`

The exception code is the following:

```html
  

  Exception: Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, 
   Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
   at USV_Control.Form_Hauptfenster.setStatusToGui(ServiceStatus status)
   at USV_Control.Form_Hauptfenster.serviceMonitor_StatusChange
   (Object sender, StatusChangeEventArgs e)
   at USV_Control.ServiceMonitoring.OnStatusChange(StatusChangeEventArgs e)
   at USV_Control.ServiceMonitoring.readCurrentStatus()
   at USV_Control.ServiceMonitoring.theConnector_PinChanged(Object sender)
   at USV_Control.ModuleConnector.OnPinChanged()
   at USV_Control.ModuleConnector.OnPortPinChanged(Object sender, SerialPinChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.CatchPinChangedEvents(Object src, SerialPinChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.EventLoopRunner.CallPinEvents(Object state)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, 
  Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

Comment: Are you sure the main form got destroyed? I think the problem it is has not been created already. You should wait for the form to be shown before trying to change anything

Comment: Yes, don't set up something that's going to want to interact with the UI until you're sure that the UI has appeared.